# Элементы массива в строку

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, вывожу из него только нужные мне значения следующим кодом:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrUs.length; i++) {
     console.log(arrUs[i][1]);
} 
//результат: one . two . three
```

Как на выходе получить строку: one;two;three ?

Пробовал так:

```
var str;
for (var i = 0; i < arrUs.length; i++) {
     console.log(arrUs[i][1]);
     str = arrUs[i][1].join(';');
}
```

Но не получается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы применяете join не к нужному вам массиву, а к элементу. str = arrUs.join(';'). Но так как у вас, как я понимаю, массив в массиве, и из второго массива вам нужен лишь второй элемент, то встроенной функцией сделать этого не получится. Так что в своём же цикле на каждой итерации прибавляйте к str строковое представление текущего элемента и ';'. После окончания цикла удалите из строки последний элемент (лишняя ';')

Comment: жаль не видно содержания самого массива... возможно поможет оборачивание arrUs[i][1] в скобки, чтобы получилось str = (arrUs[i][1]).join(';');

Answer (score 1):

`join` нужно применять на массиве, а не на конкретном элементе массива. А даже если бы он сработал, то вы всё равно на каждой итерации затираете предыдущее значение `str`.

Что можно сделать для двумерного массива:

- выбрать нужные значения в новый массив с помощью `map`
- соединить элементы нового массива в строку через разделитель с помощью `join`

Пример:

```js
var arrUs = [["1", "one"], ["2", "two"], ["3", "three"]];
var result = arrUs.map(function(value) { return value[1]; }).join(";");
console.log(result);
```

И то же самое с использованием lambda-функции:

```js
var arrUs = [["1", "one"], ["2", "two"], ["3", "three"]];
var result = arrUs.map(value => value[1]).join(";");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = ["one", "two", "three"];
var numbers_string = numbers.join(';');
console.log(numbers_string);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z5ccj5ex/23/